# Foreign Key Constraint on child won't allow to update or add field to column

Tags: insert, mysql-workbench

Trying to INSERT the following data in the student_classes table.

Receiving the following error in MySQL:
23:59:40    INSERT INTO student_classes VALUES (NULL,'1', '1', '2012-01-01', '90', '100', '80', '90', '3.0')    Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cs362lgatesip1`.`student_classes`, CONSTRAINT `FK_studentclasses_students` FOREIGN KEY (`StudentID`) REFERENCES `students` (`StudentID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)  0.141 sec

StudentID is a primary Key in the students table and a foreign key in the student_classes table both are Not Null int(11). I tried to change bit still keep getting error. What am I missing here? I tried to remove the NULL but still received the an error.

INSERT INTO student_classes
VALUES (NULL,'1', '1', '2012-01-01', '90', '100', '80', '90', '3.0');

INSERT INTO student_classes
VALUES (NULL,'1', '2', '2012-05-01', '60', '70', '80', '90', '2.70');

INSERT INTO student_classes
VALUES (NULL,'1', '3', '2012-08-01', '100', '100', '100', '95', '4.0');

INSERT INTO student_classes
VALUES (NULL,'2', '1', '2012-01-01', '85', '90', '80', '92', '3.5');

INSERT INTO student_classes
VALUES (NULL, '2', '2', '2012-05-01', '70', '75', '80', '75', '3.0');

INSERT INTO student_classes
VALUES (NULL, '2', '3', '2012-08-01', '60', '65', '70', '65', '2.5');

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can insert NULL into a foreign key column of your table.

Comment: I tried to enter a numeric value and I still get the same error. I even tried to put the value of StudentID in the students table and no change. do I need to change the foreign reference.

Comment: I meany foreign key reference, I'm sorry.

Comment: I need to put a value so that I can AVG grades for each student in a course.

Comment: you can take the average easily. I think the student IDs you are entering might not be present in the parent table that is the students table.

Comment: Try to drop the foreign key constraint and then insert a numeric value for student id.

Comment: I placed the numeric value that I used in the student table for StudentID. I have to foreign keys StudentID from students table and ClassID for classes table. But I only get an error for StudentID. I went back and deleted constraints and references. but it still shows error. I must create an index, function, and stored procedure  for the students_classes table.

Comment: I tried using some sample tables and I could create as many rows I want.

Comment: Could you send me those examples so I can see what I'm doing wrong trying to get finish tonight.

Comment: I created tables as : student(id number, name varchar2)
class(id number foreign key references student(id),marks)
Now you can add rows to the class table with the student ids present in the student table. Quite simple.....
if you tell me your exact problem I can send you the exact tables after proper checking.

Comment: I figured what I did wrong. I created a new table and named it student_classes. I was able to use  INSERT statements. Thanks for your assistance.